# ESD considerations of an open-air/wood and plexiglas case

Tags: computer-building, security, case

I am going to build a computer soon, and instead of buying a pre-built case I am planning to build my own case; either closed and built with wood and plexiglas, or open and built with just wood.

My question is, would either of those materials or an open-air case be unsafe for the components as far as ESD?

**EDIT:** found something similar to what I'm thinking (except this isn't made of wood):
http://compare.ebay.com/like/251030376877?var=lv&ltyp=AllFixedPriceItemTypes&var=sbar

Comment: Besides ESD, you should also be concerned about heat retention, (radiating) EMI and combustion.

Comment: Your good with wood if your worried about ESD, I have had open loop system running on blocks of wood before (with screws and spacers!). Not sure about enclosing it though...

Comment: For wood, don’t forget humidity as well. Sweaty cases are not ideal. As for ESD and plexi-glass, I can’t help but think of all those [nurses walking around and touching electrical medical equipment with rubber Crocs…](http://www.macleans.ca/article.jsp?content=20070604_106081_106081) (or myself walking on the carpet in the winter with rubber-soled slippers).

Answer (score 0):

Plexiglass is fine and used in many cases. It can build some static, but is not a concern for ESD. Wood does not conduct a charge very well at all. It provides good insulation.